# System.Text.Json source generation and TimeSpan

Tags: c#, serialization, system.text.json, sourcegenerators

I'm trying to use `System.Text.Json` with source generation. Unfortunately I have a class that has a `TimeSpan` data member that I need to serialize. However, I cannot get it to work with source generation, as it always tries to serialize the private data member `_ticks`.
I don't know if there's a way to disable source generation for a given type and use a user provided one instead.
I even tried to ignore the fields, but it doesn't seem to be taken into account:

```cs
[JsonSerializable(typeof(Test))]
partial class Context : JsonSerializerContext
{
}

public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public TimeSpan Span { get; set; }
}
```

Still gives the following error:

> 'TimeSpan._ticks' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Do you know if there's a workaround ?

Here is the source generated part that generates the error:
Here is part of the generated source for TimeSpan serialization, the one that causes the error, it's part of the generated `Context.TimeSpan.g.cs` file:

```cs
global::System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfoValues<global::System.Int64> info11 = new global::System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfoValues<global::System.Int64>()
{
    IsProperty = false,
    IsPublic = false,
    IsVirtual = false,
    DeclaringType = typeof(global::System.TimeSpan),
    PropertyTypeInfo = jsonContext.Int64,
    Converter = null,
    Getter = static (obj) => ((global::System.TimeSpan)obj)._ticks,
    Setter = static (obj, value) => global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.Unbox<global::System.TimeSpan>(obj)._ticks = value!,
    IgnoreCondition = null,
    HasJsonInclude = false,
    IsExtensionData = false,
    NumberHandling = default,
    PropertyName = "_ticks",
    JsonPropertyName = null
};
```

Comment: Where is TimeSpan and where are _ticks?

Comment: TimeSpan is in my class, like in the `Test` class, however the `_ticks` is in the `System.TimeSpan` class

Answer (score 0):

You should post the real code if you heed some help. You must be have some code that uses TimeSpan._ticks. Try to change it to TimeSpan.Ticks.

Comment: It's the source generator that generates the code that read and writes the _ticks. It's not my code. But I can post the source generated code if you want.

Comment: @VictorBurckel it means that source generator created the exception. Post it

Comment: Yes sure, but I would have liked to know if there was any way to bypass the source generator for a given type / member, I don't mind writing a custom generator for that type.
But I know that the exception comes from the source generated by the source generator.

Comment: @VictorBurckel It is out of the scope of the original question. You used my answer already to update your question. It is enough.